# Ranking SUM of Value Column Grouped by Date

Tags: mysql, join, sum, union, rank

I have a query which I would like to add a ranking column. My existing query has three tables as a union query, with a sum of the total order value for that week. This query produces the sum of the total order value for that week, grouped by WeekCommencing, however I am struggling to add a ranking column based on the highest to the lowest total value for that week.

My (Updated) SQLFiddle example is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1d43/35

CREATE and INSERT statements:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORD (
    WeekCommencing DATE,
    Value DECIMAL(20 , 6 ),
    Orders INT(6)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS REF (
    WeekCommencing DATE,
    Value DECIMAL(20 , 6 ),
    Orders INT(6)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SOH (
    WeekCommencing DATE,
    Value DECIMAL(20 , 6 ),
    Orders INT(6)
);

INSERT INTO ORD (WeekCommencing, Value, Orders) VALUES 
('2017-07-24',1,1),
('2017-07-31',2,1),
('2017-07-17',3,1);

INSERT INTO REF (WeekCommencing, Value, Orders) VALUES 
('2017-07-24',4,1),
('2017-07-17',5,1),
('2017-07-31',6,1);

INSERT INTO SOH (WeekCommencing, Value, Orders) VALUES 
('2017-07-17',7,1),
('2017-07-24',8,1),
('2017-07-31',9,1);
```

My best effort to date:

```
SELECT 
    WeekCommencing,
    SUM(Value) AS 'TotalValue',
    SUM(Orders) AS 'Orders',
    @r:=@r+1 As 'Rank'
 FROM
    (SELECT 
        WeekCommencing, Value, Orders
    FROM
        ORD
    GROUP BY WeekCommencing UNION ALL SELECT 
        WeekCommencing, Value, Orders
    FROM
        REF
    GROUP BY WeekCommencing UNION ALL SELECT 
        WeekCommencing, Value, Orders
    FROM
        SOH
    GROUP BY WeekCommencing) t1,  
    (SELECT @r:=0) Rank
GROUP BY WeekCommencing DESC;
```

My attempt currently ranks the order of week commencing, rather than the ranking highest to lowest.

My desired result is

```
WeekCommencing TotalValue   Orders  Rank
2017-07-31        17           3      1
2017-07-24        13           3      3
2017-07-17        15           3      2
```

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
     , @i:=@i+1 rank
  FROM 
     ( SELECT weekcommencing
            , SUM(value) totalvalue
            , COUNT(*) totalorders
         FROM 
            ( SELECT weekcommencing, value, orders FROM ord
              UNION ALL
              SELECT weekcommencing, value, orders FROM ref
              UNION ALL
              SELECT weekcommencing, value, orders FROM soh
            ) x
        GROUP
           BY weekcommencing
     ) a
     , (SELECT @i:=0) vars
 ORDER
    BY totalvalue DESC;
```

Comment: Great. That shows the rank correctly. Is it possible to have the ranking and order by WeekCommencing?

Comment: Just wrap it in another super query

Comment: Perfect. That's sorted now.